# integer pointer buffer skipping indices

Tags: c, pointers, integer, buffer, lldb

This is weird.

I have a buffer of integer pointers. I take an input, and append it to the buffer. Only, when I debug, I see that it is putting a 0 in between each input.

```
  int *buf[BUFLEN];
  char input[BUFLEN];
  int temp;
  printf("To move to the next step, enter q or quit\n");
  printf("Please enter an integer then press Enter to insert integer into the list:\n");
  while(1){
    scanf("%s", input);
    if (!strcmp(input, "q") || !strcmp(input, "quit"))
      break;
    buf[list_count] = atoi(input);
    list_count++;
  }
```

Here's what lldb is showing me

```
(lldb) p *(int(*)[20])buf
(int [20]) $19 = {
  [0] = 9
  [1] = 0
  [2] = 8
  [3] = 0
  [4] = 7
  [5] = 0
  [6] = 6
  [7] = 0
  [8] = 5
  [9] = 0
  [10] = 4
  [11] = 0
  [12] = 3
  [13] = 0
  [14] = 2
  [15] = 0
```

which is weird because when I execute p buf, it's correct -- but my overall program isn't working, so I think my bug is here

```
(lldb) p buf
(int *[256]) $17 = {
  [0] = 0x0000000000000009
  [1] = 0x0000000000000008
  [2] = 0x0000000000000007
  [3] = 0x0000000000000006
  [4] = 0x0000000000000005
  [5] = 0x0000000000000004
  [6] = 0x0000000000000003
  [7] = 0x0000000000000002
  [8] = 0x0000000000000001
```

Also, how can I assign a `atoi()` returned integer into an array of integer pointers?

that is, I have...

```
int *buf[BUFLEN];
scanf("%s", input);
buf[list_count] = atoi(input);
```

Comment: You invoke _undefined behaviour_ in multiple aspects here. So anything can happen. Worst thing it can get unnoticed, best you see a wrong effect as you do. Prepare for[ nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Your compiler should already cry; pay heed to warnings! What do you actually want to accomplish? Reading pointers from the user is definitively **not** what you want. Do you want to read integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `int` and `int*`. I'd venture a guess that on your system `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(int*) == 8`

That means that your buffer looks something like this:

```
0x00000000 0x00000009
0x00000000 0x00000008
0x00000000 0x00000007
0x00000000 0x00000006
```

If you are printing them as `int*` that will be four entries, but if you are printing them as `int` it will be 8, every second one being zero.

---

> Also, how can I assign a atoi() returned integer into an array of integer pointers?

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.. Are you trying to read a pointer(i.e. address) from the user? In that case you're doing it okayish, just need a cast, so:

```
buf[list_count] = (int*)atoi(input);
```

The compiler should have given you a warning there. Don't ignore those.

If you are trying to get the address of the int the user is giving you.. it doesn't exactly work that way. First you need to store the int somewhere, in a separate `int intbuffer[BUFSIZE];`, and then use the address of that element.

Comment: There is no need to even think about a specific layout. It is undefined behaviour, that's all that counts.

Comment: On my computer, gcc outputs a warning on the assignment, even without any switches like -Wall.

Comment: @Olaf Sure, but an explanation about why a certain bug outputs a certain result won't do any harm.

Comment: so what you're saying is that the buf is being properly filled, it's just that my lldb print statement is off?

Comment: @MrLister: Right, but the answer does not even mention this most relevant issue. As given, it sound like this is just a minor flaw.

Comment: @kendall Yes, if I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to load the pointers from the user, or do you want a pointer to the number user mentioned? (edited answer)

Comment: There is absolutely no use in reading addresses from the user. They will all be invalid per definition.

Comment: @Olaf There are many uses for doing so, it's just very unlikely the OP is doing anything like that. You could, for example, have mmio registers where you don't know the addresses at compile time, but are going to pipe them to stdin from a separate program that gets them.

Comment: @mtijanic: You should get them from system functions, syssfs/procfs or similar. Reading such from the user/an external pipe is recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Olaf Agreed, it was tongue in cheek. Every time you are reading an address from stdin, it's a major red flag. But the point remains that there are cases when you get an int (not from stdin!) and want to treat it as a pointer. Things like TTL, VGA framebuffer, bar0 of the pcie device, or just a virtual address of a child process who's memory you are inspecting. Or maybe your system uses pagefaults for syscalls, and then looks at which VA you faulted on. I'm almost certain the OP doesn't want any of this.

Comment: @mtijanic: Getting an **`int`** and converting to a pointer is **always** a bad idea. Iff you really need to have an integer converted to a pointer, make sure that is a `uintptr_t` or (less preferable) a `intptr_t`. Anything else is likely to fail on some target. For MMIO, this is a driver/kernel matter and the kernel provides appropriate functions to get them. Note that I did not say the conversion as such is obsolete. Either way, it is not a matter of application code, but drivers. And anyone accessing hardware on CPUs larger than PIC16 or AVR 8bit without a driver should be punished.

Comment: not necessarily true.   Actually the <newline> from the user pressing enter is being passed over, when that is all that is left in the input stream, but the scanf(), on every other call, will get no characters into `input` and will still insert a trailing NUL byte,  what single/leading NUL byte is interpreted by `atoi()` and results in 0 being set into buf[]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your posted code (shown here with comments)

```
  int *buf[BUFLEN];   // array of pointers to integers
  char input[BUFLEN]; // array of characters
  int temp;           // unused variable

  printf("To move to the next step, enter q or quit\n");
  printf("Please enter an integer then press Enter to insert integer into the list:\n");

  while(1)
  {
    scanf("%s", input);   // inputs unlimited number of characters
                          //     (ended by use pressing enter)
                          // fails to check returned value (not parameter value)
                          //     to assure op was successful)

    if (!strcmp(input, "q") || !strcmp(input, "quit")) 
      break;

    buf[list_count] = atoi(input); // tries to convert input from char string to integer
                                   // and place result into some pointer
                                   // which raises compiler warning
    list_count++;                  // undefined variable
  }
```

Has several problems:

1. declares an array of pointers to integers rather than an array of integers when declaring `buf[]`,  To declare an array of integers, use `int buf[BUFLEN];`
2. The call to `scanf()` fails to place a limit on the number of characters the user is allowed to input.  This allows the user to overrun the `input[]` buffer, resulting in *undefined behaviour* which can lead to a seg fault event
3. the call to `scanf()` fails to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful
4. fails on every other call to `scanf()` because makes no provision to consume the `<newline>` from the input stream. (and `scanf()` stops inputting characters when any `white space` is encountered (like the white space produced by the user hitting the 'enter' key)

The comments list some other problems in the posted code.

Suggest the code be more like the following:

```
  int  buf[BUFLEN];   // array of integers
  char input[BUFLEN]; // array of characters   

  printf("To move to the next step, enter q or quit\n");
  printf("Please enter an integer then press Enter to insert integer into the list:\n");

  // note limiting the number of inputs so do not overrun `buf[]`
  for( int list_count=0; list_count < BUFLEN; list_count++ )
  {    
       // note checking returned value
       // note leading space in format string to consume white space
       // note limiting number of char that user can input
       if( 1 != (scanf("% *s", BUFLEN-1, input) ) )
       {
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
       }

       // implied else, scanf successful

       if (!strcmp(input, "q") || !strcmp(input, "quit")) 
           break;

       buf[list_count] = atoi(input);
  } // end for
```